# User privileges design in OO: embedded methods vs. program execution control

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am rather confused about this issue since awhile now.

Say, I have to design an OO system in which the admins would be the only users who can register new students in the college. Now, I have (obviously) other users for the system. How should I control these privileges being only applicable when the user is an admin?

I have though of two possibilities: embedding these roles as functions inside the `Admin` class that communicates with `Student` class , or just controlling the registration of new students in program execution, such as:

```
if(user_type() == 'a') register_student(); // a type means an admin user

else cout << "Access denied";

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this that are OO:

```
if( user->has_permission( REGISTER_STUDENT ) ) {
  register_student();
}
```

This is asking the user instance if it has permission to register a student. Another way:

```
 if( user->in_role( ROLE_ADMIN ) ) {
   register_student();
 }
```

The issue I have with the code is that it exposes the internal details about how an administrator role is determined. The letter `a` will eventually lose context and become meaningless for a status to new maintainers; whereas, the constants `ROLE_ADMIN`/`REGISTER_STUDENT` clarify the intent of the code without needing additional comments.

It's not really the responsibility of the `User` class or `Admin` class to perform the registration. It does make sense for a `Student` to register itself:

```
 if( user->in_role( ROLE_ADMIN ) ) {
   student->register();
 }
```

This code I would expect to see in a `Controller` class. The `Controller` class would be able to examine the user interface objects to determine:

- what student is currently selected
- what option the user selected from the interface
- what role the user is in

You could implement the following:

```
if( user->is_admin() ) {
  student->register();
}
```

While the code is extremely clear, it is less flexible as you might want to leave open the following possibility:

```
if( controller->can_execute( user, action ) ) {
  action->execute();
}
else {
  controller->execute_error( user, action );
}
```

This provides a much more flexible system in that roles can be assigned to actions dynamically. For example, you could map the method `student->register()` to `ROLE_ADMIN`. This keeps all security constraints throughout the entire application in a single location, greatly simplifying maintenance.

It can also be further simplified:

```
controller->execute( user, action );
```

Then the execute method would resemble:

```
void execute( User user, Action action ) {
  if( can_execute( user, action ) ) {
    action->execute();
  }
  else {
    error( user, action );
  }
}

bool can_execute( User user, Action action ) {
  return user->is_in_role( action->get_role() );
}
```

Implementation details for how the permission errors are displayed (a dialog box vs. `cout`) is now abstracted. Further, error messages can be more comprehensive such as:

```
"User registration is restricted to the administrator role."
```

Encoded as the following string:

```
"%s is restricted to the %s role."
```

The controller class can substitute for `%s` automatically.